# What's the best way to find specific column in amCharts XYChart?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I need to trigger hover of a specific column and/or segment in an XYChart (amCharts). I've managed to make it work, however it feels like there should be an easier way.

The scenario is that the chart data is also displayed in a table next to the chart. When a row in the table is hovered, I want to set hover of the corresponding column.

The data looks something like this:

```
const data = [{
  x: 'Kalle',
  value: 12,
  meta: {id: 12432341}
},{
  x: 'Nisse',
  value: 20,
  meta: {id: 54251114}
},{
  x: 'Bosse',
  value: 8,
  meta: {id: 16517346}
}]
```

And the chart is built like this:

```
const chart = am4core.create('chartArea', am4charts.XYChart)

// Add category axis
const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis())
xAxis.data = categories.map((c) => ({x: c}))
xAxis.dataFields.category = 'x'

// Add value axis
const axis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis())

// Add column series
const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries())
series.data = data
series.dataFields.valueY = 'value'
series.dataFields.categoryX = 'x'
series.yAxis = axis
series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())

series.columns.template.interactionsEnabled = true
const hs = series.columns.template.states.create('hover')
hs.properties.strokeWidth = 8

const bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
```

And then the function that should find a specific column and set hover:

```
setHover(chart, id) {
  let xPosition
  chart.series.each(series => {

    if (!xPosition) {
      const data = series.data.find(d => d.meta && d.meta.id === id)
      if (!data) {
        return
      }

      xPosition = chart.xAxes.getIndex(0).dataItems.values.findIndex(v => v.category === data.x)
    }

    const column = series.columns.getIndex(xPosition)
    if (column) {
      column.isHover = true
    }
  })
}
```

While this works, I'd prefer to identify the column directly instead of going by the category axis position. This would make more sense to me:

```
setHover(chart, id) {
  chart.series.each(series => {
    const column = series.columns.values.find(column => column.dataItem.meta.id === id)
    if (column) {
      column.isHover = value
    }
  })
}
```

Or, could it be done with adapter instead?

What's the most straight forward way?